# PHP implode() vs sprintf() vs concat

Tags: php, benchmarking

Which is faster to use when generating strings ? `implode()`, `sprintf()` or the regular concatenation of variables ?

Why, you ask? It might not intrigue you to test such a small detail about generating strings since who cares it's all in **ms** right ? Not really! Not when you have to generate tons of strings out of given variables which is when the smalles **0.00xms** would make a difference. In my case it was generating *cache keys* out of a given prefix, content type and an identifier.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly simple concatenation; but why can't you actually test this yourself?

Comment: @MarkBaker I did answer it myself posting the results.

Comment: Of course, there is also `echo "{$id}:{$type}:{$prefix}";` which is likely to be fractionally faster than any of your other options
`

Comment: For 524288 iterations each (assigning to a variable rather than echoing the string) implode took 0.3941 seconds;
sprintf took 0.4779 seconds;
concat took 0.2437 seconds;
interpolation took 0.1788 seconds on my development box.

Answer (score -7):

So I've done this on a very simple, minimalistic data set.

Here are the results and the code follows:

**Results**

> - comments:article:123456 implode took: 0.00011706352233887
> - comments:article:123456 sprintf took: 2.4080276489258E-5
> - comments:article:123456 concat took: 6.9141387939453E-6
> - concat is fastest!

**Code**

```
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}


// vars

$id = 123456;
$type = 'article';
$prefix = 'comments';


$implode_time_start = microtime_float();

echo implode(':', array($prefix, $type, $id));

echo "\n";

$implode_time_end = microtime_float();
$implode_time = $implode_time_end - $implode_time_start;

echo "implode took: $implode_time";

echo "-----\n\n\n";


$sprintf_time_start = microtime_float();

echo sprintf('%s:%s:%s', $prefix, $type, $id);

echo "\n";

$sprintf_time_end = microtime_float();
$sprintf_time = $sprintf_time_end - $sprintf_time_start;

echo "sprintf took: $sprintf_time";

echo "-----\n\n\n";


$concat_time_start = microtime_float();

echo $prefix.':'.$type.':'.$id;

echo "\n";

$concat_time_end = microtime_float();
$concat_time = $concat_time_end - $concat_time_start;

echo "concat took: $concat_time";

echo "------\n\n\n";


if ($implode_time < $sprintf_time || $implode_time < $concat_time) {
    echo "implode is fastest!";
} elseif ($concat_time < $sprintf_time) {
    echo "concat is fastest!";
} else {
    echo "sprintf is fastest!";
}
```

Please do share your thoughts!

Comment: Add this to question. Don't give the extra details as answer. Edit your question

Comment: If I'm being honest I think this is a pretty cheap karma grab, but at any rate you should at least run each test a number of times, say 1,000 times each. Just once is pointless and tells you nothing.